# R Markdown: Plot corruption

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

The following bit of code works great as a chunk, and knits fine, and the html looks fine in the RStudio viewer. However, when I open the html in a browser (Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181, or Safari) each histogram has overlapping bars, and adjusting lwd in the points() calls doesn't help. I am running OSX 10.9.5, R 3.3.3, and RStudio 1.1.383. I'm aware that there are easier ways to put two histograms on the same plot, but I'd like to understand what is going on here; RStudio/RMarkdown have always worked flawlessly for me. Thanks. -n

[image: How it looks in a browser]

My apologies. Here is the entire Rmd. (The YAML headers ARE here, but they refuse to appear, even as a block quote. Forgive my ignorance.)

title: "Odd plot behavior"
  author: "Neil Frazer"
  date: "March 24, 2018"
  output: 
  html_document
  fig_caption: yes

````
<style type="text/css">
h1.title{/* Normal */ font-size:20px}
body{ /* Normal  */ font-size: 14px}
td {  /* Table   */ font-size: 12px}
h1 { /* Header 1 */ font-size: 16px}
h2 { /* Header 2 */ font-size: 14px}
h3 { /* Header 3 */ font-size: 14px}
h4 { /* Header 4 */ font-size: 13px}
code.r{ /* Code block */ font-size: 14px}
pre { /* Code block */ font-size: 14px}
p.caption {font-size: 14px}
</style>

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
rm(list=ls()) # clean up
library(knitr)
#library(coda)
gr <- (1+sqrt(5))/2 # golden ratio, for figures
opts_chunk$set(comment="  ",
               collapse=TRUE, 
               echo=FALSE,
               fig.asp=1/gr,
               fig.height=5,
               dev="svg",
               warning=TRUE
               )
opts_knit$set(eval.after = "fig.cap") 
```  

```{r histograms, out.width=800, out.height=400}
# synthetic data for test
daysAdlib <- abs( rnorm(200,mean=300,sd=100) )
daysRestr <- abs( rnorm(200,mean=500,sd=100) )
unit      <- 50L
break1 <- unit*floor(min(daysAdlib,daysRestr)/unit)
break2 <- unit*ceiling(max(daysAdlib,daysRestr)/unit)
breaks <- seq(from=break1,to=break2, by=unit)
histRestr <- hist(daysRestr, plot=FALSE, breaks=breaks)
histAdlib <- hist(daysAdlib, plot=FALSE, breaks=breaks)
xlim <- range(breaks)
ylim <- range(0, 1.05*max(histAdlib$density,histRestr$density) )
myred  <- rgb(255,0,0,max=255,alpha=120,names="blue50")
myblue <- rgb(0,0,255,max=255,alpha=120,names="red50" )
plot(0,0, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, type="n",
     xlab="Days lived", ylab="density") 
lwd <- unit/2 
points(histAdlib$mids, histAdlib$density, type="h",
      col=myblue, lwd=lwd, lend="butt")
points(histRestr$mids, histRestr$density, type="h",
      col=myred, lwd=lwd, lend="butt")
legend("topright", inset=0.05,
       col=c(myblue,myred), 
       pch=c(15,15),
       pt.cex=c(1.5,1.5),
       legend=c("Ad lib","Restricted")
       )
```
````

Comment: Can you include an image of the bad output you're getting (and expected output if you're able to produce it)? I can run your code fine but not sure what the issue with the resulting plot is.

Comment: I don't see output to a graphics file device. How exactly is Chrome supposed to be viewing this?

Comment: @42-, perhaps the OP is referring to the "self_contained" option of `html_document`? Neil, it might be useful to include the top yaml and enclosing rmarkdown for this document, so that it is truly reproducible.

Comment: Thanks folks. Here is the entire Rmd.

Comment: Use the chunk options `out.width` and `out.height`, (use pixels for an HTML document). The default is probably 300 px wide, bump it up.

Comment: out.width=800, out.height=400 in the chunk header made no difference to the html.

Comment: Code above is current, and there is now an image from the browser.

Comment: Are you sure adjusting `lwd` doesn't help? I can reproduce your problem when `lwd` is > 30, but don't see any problems with `lwd <= 20`. I think that makes sense, I don't think I'm seeing any unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Many thanks everyone! Using out.width, and out.height, and reducing lwd has solved the problem.